# How to set Default value in Swt Combo box?

Tags: java, swt

I have a combo box which will be in read-only mode. I want to set a default value to that combo box indicating the purpose of the combo box (eg.: A location combo with default text as 'Location' with number of other items like USA, India, England etc. in combo box). 
Note : The default value should not be one of the items in the combo box. 
I know that it is not possible if combo box is in read-only mode.
Please let me know if any workaround possible.

As shown in the below image, there is a combo box with different variants like A,B,C,D etc. but the combo box has the default label 'Variante'.

[image]

Comment: You want to display something over the value of a read only component?

Comment: @UsagiMiyamoto yes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved using a [`CCombo`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCCombo.html). If you set the items on the combo using [`setItems(String[])`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCCombo.html&anchor=setItems-java.lang.String:A-), *before* you use [`setText(String)`](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Fcustom%2FCCombo.html&anchor=setText-java.lang.String-), you will see a default value in the combo which is not one of the items in the list.

Notice that when you call `getSelectionIndex()`, the returned value will be `-1`, because no item has yet been selected, and once an item has been selected, the default value will no longer be present.

```
public class CComboDefaultTextTest {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final Display display = new Display();
        final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
        shell.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final Composite baseComposite = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
        baseComposite
                .setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
        baseComposite.setLayout(new GridLayout());

        final CCombo combo = new CCombo(baseComposite, SWT.READ_ONLY
                | SWT.BORDER);
        combo.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false));
        // Be sure to do this before calling setText()
        combo.setItems(new String[] { "item 1", "item 2", "item 3" });
        combo.setText("Default");

        System.out.println(combo.getSelectionIndex());

        shell.pack();
        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]